# How to subtract the squareroot of every value in the single column of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, and I need to subtract the square root of each value from the 2nd column.

So I need to turn this:

```
array([[ 0,  9],
       [ 2,  16],
       [ 4,  25],
       [10, 36]])
```

into:

```
array([[ 0,  6],
       [ 2,  12],
       [ 4,  20],
       [10, 30]])
```

What I have so far is:

`B[:, 1] -= np.sqrt(B[:, 1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
arr = np.array([ [0, 9],
                 [2,  16], 
                 [4,  25],
                 [10, 36]])

arr[:,1] = arr[:,1] - np.sqrt(arr[:,1])

>arr
array([[ 0,  6],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 4, 20],
       [10, 30]])
```

Comment: oo. I was wondering why the T.

Comment: The question was changed. At first glance, it seemed like the subtraction was to be applied to each element in the array. My bad. However, this would have required duplication of the columns via `tile()`. This, in turn, necessitated turning the row into a column. Hence the transposed symbol `.T`. Only then, the `-=` operator works since both NumPy arrays are of the same shape. Regardless, the edit made it clear that the subtraction only applies to a single column.

Answer (score 1):

does it have to be in numpy?
I like pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[ 2,  16],
[ 4,  25],
[10, 36]])

df[1] = df[1]-df[1]**.5

print(df.to_numpy())
```

output

```
[[ 2. 12.]
 [ 4. 20.]
 [10. 30.]]
```